# tkprogressbar doesn't fit the window

Tags: r, user-interface, progress-bar, tk-toolkit

I am programming a GUI and want to use a progress bar. My code:

```
    load <- function(x,y){
      k <- 10

     bar <- tkProgressBar(title = "Bla ...",
                    label = "Progress", 
                    0, ## minimum value
                    100, ## maximal value
                    0 ## initial value,
                     )

# show progress

    j <- i/length(data)*100
    if(j<k){
    } else{
      loading <- sprintf("%d%% ready",round(k))

      setTkProgressBar(pb = bar,
                       value = k, 
                       title = sprintf("Load Data.. (%s)", loading)
      )
     k <- k+10
    }
```

This is really working fine, but if the Window with the progress bar appears, you can't see the progress bar, because the window is too small!
I first have to adjust the window to see the bar. Is there a way, the window is in the right size for the bar??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what library you use. If that's `library(tcltk)`, consider switching to `library(tcltk2)`. If you are already using the latter, there's a parameter `width` for it. The example is adapted from `?tkProgressBar`:

```
demo <- function(w)
{
  pb <- tkProgressBar("test progress bar", "Some information in %",
                      0, 100, 50, width=w)
  Sys.sleep(1)
  u <- c(0, sort(runif(20, 0, 100)), 100)
  for(i in u) 
  {
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    info <- sprintf("%d%% done", round(i))
    setTkProgressBar(pb, i, sprintf("test (%s)", info), info)
  }
  Sys.sleep(2)
  close(pb)
}

demo(100)
demo(500)
```

Comment: Thanks, now it is long enough, but I cannot change the height.. And it still disappears. Maybe I have to live with it.

Comment: It disappears when you call `close(pb)`, delay this if you want it to hang around for a longer period of time. Also take a look at `winProgressBar` if you are under Windows.

Comment: No, I mean, the progress bar still disappears, because the window is not high enough. But there is no other possibility I think.